# How to see that $[\textbf{p}^2,\textbf{L}^2]=[\textbf{p}^4,\textbf{L}^2]=0$ without doing any messy algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

The Hamiltonian of a particle moving under the influence of a central potential $V(r)$ given by $$H=\frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2m}+V(r)$$ commutes with $\textbf{L}^2\equiv L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2$. Without doing a long algebra, is there a way to see that the operators $\textbf{p}^2$ and $\textbf{p}^4$ commute with $\textbf{L}^2$?

Comment: Note that $[AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C] B$.  So if $[p^2, L^2] = 0$, then it follows that $[p^4, L^2] = p^2 [p^2, L^2] + [p^2, L^2] p^2 = 0$.

Comment: You can even take a step back from the commutator rules; $[A, B] = 0$ means $AB = BA$ in an already-associative algebra. To ask if $[A^2, B]=0$ is then easily proven by $AAB = ABA = BAA.$ What remains is the $\mathbf p^2$ case which is a nontrivial thing that has to do with scalars being invariant under rotations.

Comment: Maybe the down votes are coming because the first sentence seems unrelated to the question? As such you have a single sentence question repeated both in the title and in the body of the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbf{A}$ is a vector operator, i.e its components transform as a vector under rotation,
$$[L_i, A_j] = i \epsilon_{ijk} A_k.$$
Using this definition gives $[\mathbf{L}, \mathbf{A}^2] = 0$, which just says that $\mathbf{A}^2$ is a rotational scalar. Then the commutator product rule implies $[\mathbf{L}^2, \mathbf{A}^2] = [\mathbf{L}^2, \mathbf{A}^4] = 0$ as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: ${\bf r}$ and ${\bf p}$ are vectors (while ${\bf r}^2$ and ${\bf p}^2$ are scalars) under $SO(3)$-rotations generated by ${\bf L}$. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366686/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: More like the answer rather than a hint :P

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are happy with $[{\bf p^2},{\bf L^2}]=0$ already. Using $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$ with $A=B={\bf p^2}$ and $C={\bf A^2}$ gives \begin{equation}
[{\bf p^4},{\bf L^2}] ={\bf p^2}[{\bf p^2},{\bf L^2}] + [{\bf p^2},{\bf L^2}]{\bf p^2} = 0
\end{equation}
and of course you can go on like that to show $[{\bf p^{2n}},{\bf L^2}]=0$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$.